# JQuery - Call server side event in client side in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two buttons like

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="vgSave" CssClass="submit3"
                        Width="100px" Height="38px" OnClientClick="raiseEvent()" />

    <asp:Button ID="btnTemp" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" CssClass="hidden"/>
```

and I want to call `OnClick` of `btnTemp` using javascript as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function raiseEvent() {
            $('#<%= btnTemp.ClientID %>').click();
        }
    </script>
```

but it do not work for me. But when I call it on `document.ready()` (just to test) it works, see code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%= btnTemp.ClientID %>').click();
        });
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think when you click on `btnSave` button call your function '`raiseEvent`' but your `btnSave` is a `asp` button and it convert into HTML submit button so when you click on button it post form to server so page cant wait until `btnTemp` click..

if you want to stop postback via `btnsave` click your function must be `return false`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="vgSave" CssClass="submit3"
                        Width="100px" Height="38px" OnClientClick="return raiseEvent()" />

<script>
                function raiseEvent() {
                    $('#<%= btnTemp.ClientID %>').click();
                    return false;
                }

</script>
```